# How to run a script which requires a private key completely in a browser?

Tags: transactions, ethers.js, javascript, security, browsers

For a non-technical person I need to create a page on my website, in the **admin area,** in which he'd regularly do stuff that normally is done on local machine only. That is, a person doesn't want to go as low as to run JS script on his local machine. There may be risks of running them on a web page and he's aware of them.

I'd create a web page on which a private key(s) will be entered **dynamically** via a pop up, as well as the public keys or addresses of the recepients. And a script will then send some TXs.

A script must run **completely in the browser** -- on the client side only.

That is, **no private key must leave the browser during the process.** And there must no be traces of them left afterwards on the server. Some information may be delivered **from** the backend such as private API keys, config values.

How can  I implement it in ethers.js? And will this be possible in the browser, on the client side at all?

I know how to send TXs, but - on the server side only.